# Как изменить значение переменной $who на Vasia ?? Переменная $who сохраняет значение "All"

Tags: perl

```
  my $who = "All";

  my $hash = { hellow => "Hellow $who"};

  print( $hash -> { hellow },"\n");

  $who = "Vasia";

  print( $hash -> { hellow },"\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Строки, заключенные в двойные кавычки `"` обеспечивают интерполяцию (**переменные, включенные в строку заменяются на их содержимое**), а также в них заменяются специальные escape-последовательности, например `\n` заменяется на перевод строки, а `\t` - на табуляцию.

```
my $name = 'Foo';
my $time  = "сегодня";
print "Привет $name,\nкак у тебя дела $time?\n\n";

my @friends = ('Margaret', 'Richard', 'Carolyn');
print "Friends: @friends\n";
```

Вывод:

```
Привет Foo,
как у тебя дела сегодня?

Friends: Margaret Richard Carolyn
```

В твоём коде `$hash->{hellow}` было вычислено при инициализации (произошла интерполяция) и не зависит от дальнейших модификаций переменной `$who`. Если в `$hash->{hellow}` должен появится "Vasia" - нужно записать новое значение:

```
$who = "Vasia";
$hash->{hellow} = "Hellow $who";
say $hash->{hellow};
```

Answer (score 0):

**TIM-FU&^%NG-TOWTDI** (Возможно, ответ не является правильным)

Взял я ваш код, и сделал так, как вижу я:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my $who = "All";

my $hash = { hellow => "Hellow $who"};

print( $hash -> { hellow },"\n");



sub Vasya {
$who = "Vasya";
my $hash = { hellow => "Hellow $who"};
print( $hash -> { hellow },"\n");
}

print Vasya();
```

В любом случае, сначала печатает `Hellow All`, затем `Hello Vasya`

Answer (score 0):

Как уже написали, интерполяция переменных - процедура одноразовая. После того, как она произошла здесь:

`my $hash = { hellow => "Hellow $who"};`

изменения переменной `$who` уже ни на что не влияют.

Не совсем понятно чего именно хочется добиться, но если задача - изменять значение ключа хэша, то можно рассмотреть такой вариант:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;

my %hash;

set_hello(\%hash, 'All');
say $hash{hello};
# или
# say set_hello(\%hash, 'All');

set_hello(\%hash, 'Vasya');
say $hash{hello};
# или
# say set_hello(\%hash, 'All');

sub set_hello
{
    my ($hash, $who) = @_;
    $hash->{hello} = "Hello, $who";
    return wantarray ? %{$hash} : $hash;
    # или 
    # return $hash->{hello};
}
```